# Convert Pandas DF column from UTC to US-Eastern time without date

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, timezone

I have this Pandas dataframe column:

```
                     time_UTC
0   2015-01-05 16:44:34+00:00
1   2015-08-11 16:44:38+00:00
2   2015-08-02 16:53:25+00:00
3   2015-08-17 16:53:25+00:00
4   2015-09-28 16:53:26+00:00
Name: time_UTC, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

and I converted it from UTC to US-Eastern timezone using:

```
list_temp = []
    for row in df['time_UTC']:
        list_temp.append(Timestamp(row, tz = 'UTC').tz_convert('US/Eastern'))
    df['time_EST'] = list_temp
```

to get this:

```
0   2015-01-05 11:44:34-05:00
1   2015-08-11 11:44:38-05:00
2   2015-08-02 11:53:25-05:00
3   2015-08-17 11:53:25-05:00
4   2015-09-28 11:53:26-05:00
Name: time_EST, dtype: datetime64[ns, US/Eastern]
```

Now, I need to drop the date part of the entries so that I only get the time. Here is what I need:

```
0   11:44:34-05:00
1   11:44:38-05:00
2   11:53:25-05:00
3   11:53:25-05:00
4   11:53:26-05:00
Name: time_EST, dtype: datetime64[ns, US/Eastern]
```

**Attempt:**

I tried this:

```
print df['time_EST'].apply(lambda x: dt.time(x.hour,x.minute,x.second))
```

The conversion is made so that date is dropped and I only get time. But it is reverting back to the UTC timezone. Here is the output of the above command:

```
0    16:44:34
1    16:44:38
2    16:53:25
3    16:53:25
4    16:53:26
Name: time_EST, dtype: object
```

**Question:**

Is there a way to drop the date and keep time as US-Eastern, without automatically reverting back to UTC?

**EDIT:**

To recreate the problem, just copy the first DataFrame above and use this code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.lib import Timestamp
import datetime as dt
df = pd.read_clipboard()
```

Then copy the remaining lines of code from the question. Any assistance with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: in the output you pasted above, it looks like it's staying in EST time?

Comment: The desired output is the third dataframe from the top and it shows the first row as `0   11:44:34-05:00` and this is in EST. This is what I would like to get and this is the correct format - currently my code doesn't produce this output. My attempt gave `0   2015-01-05 11:44:34-05:00` which is shown in the 2nd dataframe from the top and it has the time in EST but it also has the date - my required output should only have the time in EST. So yes, the output is staying in EST, but it is in the wrong format. When I try to change the format (fourth dataframe) it has reverted back to UTC.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want to use `strftime` to format your string, also note the vectorized date manipulations:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()
df.time_UTC = pd.to_datetime(df.time_UTC)
df['EST'] = (df.time_UTC.dt.tz_localize('UTC')
                        .tz_convert('US/Eastern')
                        .strftime("%H:%M:%S"))

In [41]: df
Out[41]:
                               time_UTC       EST
time_UTC
2016-02-15 16:44:34 2016-02-15 16:44:34  11:44:34
2016-02-15 16:44:38 2016-02-15 16:44:38  11:44:38
2016-02-15 16:53:25 2016-02-15 16:53:25  11:53:25
2016-02-15 16:53:25 2016-02-15 16:53:25  11:53:25
2016-02-15 16:53:26 2016-02-15 16:53:26  11:53:26
```

Comment: I'm having trouble replicating your solution maxymoo. Does `df['EST'] = (df.index.tz_localize('UTC')
                     .tz_convert('US/Eastern')
                     .strftime("%H:%M:%S"))` come after `df['time_EST'] = list_temp`?

Comment: @ W R I've included the steps i used to import the data, forget about list temp, i've rewritten that step for you in my answer

Comment: I had to add a call to ".dt" in-between the localize and tz_convert and in between tz_convert and strftime, otherwise pandas was providing a series object.
    df.time_UTC.dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('US/Eastern').dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

Answer (score 1):

**pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert:**
Convert tz-aware Datetime Array/Index from one time zone to another.

```
df['est_time'] = df['time_UTC'].dt.tz_convert('US/Eastern')

df['est_time'] = df['est_time'].dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

print(df['est_time'])
```

which produce output like:

```
0 12:44:34
1 12:44:38
2 12:53:25
3 12:53:25
4 12:53:26
```